# Menu of Pictures -> Send By iphone

Tags: ios4, menu, image

I'm prompt to make a menu like the menu that appears in pictures -> send to on iphone.

Some one knows if the buttons menu is a "standard" control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks I'm sorry for the noob question :P